# Why didn't cpu clock frequency plateau at two orders of magnitude higher Hz?

Tags: frequency, cpu, clock-speed

Here is a back of the envelope estimate for an upper bound of clock frequency for modern CPU's:

The speed of light is 3·10⁸ m/s which is 3·10¹¹ mm/s, and I assume the speed of electricity is about 50% to 99% of that ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity)), so let's conservatively say 1.5·10¹¹ mm/s.

If we assume that during a single clock cycle, a signal has to travel about 1 millimetre (a conservative, i.e. large estimate I think), to go from a register through an ALU to another register (this is not even taking into account pipelining, so that it has to travel less than that), then that means we should expect that with current transistor sizes, the clock frequency can be set at about 1.5·10¹¹ = 150 GHz.

Yet in practice, clock frequency seems to have plateaud at about 2 GHz. What is wrong with my back of the envelope calculation? Why can't we get two orders of magnitude higher frequency?

Comment: Power dissipation in CMOS grows by the square of the frequency. Right now, a CPU has extremely high power density.

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions. Have you considered if the assumptions are valid? And are you talking about consumer CPUs or some other CPUs? Even cheap consumer CPUs go past 4 GHz and near 5 GHz.

Comment: @Justme, "Have you considered if the assumptions are valid?" .... yes that's why I asked this question...

Comment: @LiorBilia Linearly with frequency but square with voltage. P ~= V^2fC/2

Comment: There is no requirement that a clock cycle be long enough for light to reach the width of a circuit. Often for things like buses the far end of the circuit will be further away than light can travel in 1 cycle. If you want to take this logic to it's conclusion you should ask why CPU frequency is not infinite. The reason is that transistors are capacitors that must be charged and discharged at finite rate, which is relatively slow.

Comment: @user1850479, yeah I get now that the capacitor charge and discharge is the limiting factor. Though the speed of electricity really also gives a (non-limiting) bound on useful clock frequency.

Comment: @user56834 it really doesn't! It gives a maximum size on clock domain sizes where you don't need to think about asynchronizity / metastable behaviour, but as Hearth said below: not much to do with "useful frequency", just means that a simplifying assumption doesn't hold anymore, but it's not a "special" assumption. A lot of other simplfiying assumptions also don't hold anymore.

Comment: *"Linearly with frequency but square with voltage"* True, but if you consider that in practice higher clocks require higher voltage too...

Comment: @MarcusMüller, this just seems wrong, given that if I have a circuit, and it takes x time for an electric signal to pass through, and I can't pipeline it further than I already have (e.g. after every parallel set of logic gates I've put a register), and my frequency is such that during each cycle, a signal passes through one such gate, then additional clock frequency will not have an effect. Admittedly this gives an upper bound on frequency many OOMs above the current range, so it is not evne close to limiting.

Comment: but that's the thing: you can pipeline. There's no need that your first result needs to be ready while the circuitry on the other end already calculates the next. You need signal propagation to be done for all paths leading to a single transistor, but that's a localized problem, not a global problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, ok that's what you meant, yes I was taking it into account, just giving a very conservative estimate of the pipelining.

Comment: but that's not only a pessimistic view on pipelining, it also neglects the fact that a CPU is multiple (many!) data-coupled, but independently operating systems. A transistor in the adder of the 8. CPU core has *never* to wait for the output  of a register file transistor in the 3. core, or for a PCIe root complex transistor. You gotta be careful which assumptions you make – "everything waits on everything" is an overly strong assumption and I really don't see how that would represent what a CPU *is*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I was not explicitly assuming that everything waits on everything. I'm not sure why it looks like I was assuming that (i.e. what mistake I made that implies a misunderstanding about that. btw, I'm not denying that I am misunderstanding this)

Comment: don't worry! Your whole calculation in your question is based on light having to travel 1mm. It doesn't, you're making a local problem (path length differences in the 20nm to 10µm before you need to compensate slew) a practically global problem, which it isn't, luckily!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Ah I see, I was just being extremely conservative about the size of an adder-circuit here. Anyway, Thanks a lot for the discussion, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations' shortcomings:

- speed of light in vacuum > speed in a medium
- speed of light is not the limiting factor, anyways, as there's no need for things to happen at the same time; the clock edges at one end of the chip do not have to occur before the next one happens at the other end!
- you're omitting the actually limiting factors, which is speed of charge transfer and semiconductor operations. Can't instantly make a field effect transistor stop conducting current!
- Switching faster requires proportionally higher currents (to exchange the same charge in less time), means quadratically increased losses. So, you're very quickly thermally limited. What good is it if you can run twice as fast, but since you can't get the heat away quickly enough, need to shut down 3/4 of the time?
- CPUs [do exist beyond 5 GHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_z15_(microprocessor)), but for the thermal reasons quoted above, and the fact that having a fast CPU alone is not the solution to needing fast compute that is affordable, you won't find these in PCs or most servers. You'll find them in highly custom mainframe settings, where hardware cost of cooling system integration is supported by the use case (i.e., the cost per operations per second might not be as important as the possible operations per second; that's a different market than desktop computing or hyperscalers; not saying these are not possibly cost-efficient for some workloads, but you can't sell a z15 CPU without the cooling system, and IBM has nothing to win commerically by selling small systems with large support envelope; AWS, GCP, Alicloud, Azure… on the other hand, has nothing to win commercially by making themselves depend on a single vendor).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136659/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-why-didnt-cpu-clock-frequency-plateau-at).

Answer (score 4):

Moore's law kept struggling but [Dennard Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennard_scaling) broke down about 15 years ago. Transistor capacitance and voltage would keep getting smaller, but power density was not kept constant, mainly due to leakage in the smaller transistors.

The old truth about power consumption being dominated by dynamic power (switching losses) started to loose its strength due to an increasing number of smaller transistors. Despite this, it is not uncommon to see embedded processors or notebooks which run at their max. frequency for just a few seconds before throttling down the clock.

See how it started getting worse by the same time total power dissipation stopped increasing at the same rate (but it kept rising, despite the fact the clock rates stopped at a few GHz):

[image]

*[Source](https://github.com/karlrupp/microprocessor-trend-data)*